# Spyder won't load

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda, spyder

I've installed in Windows 10 Anaconda 1.8.7 with Python 3.6.5 and Spyder 3.2.8

The issue is the following : when I launch Spyder from Anaconda navigator Spyder freeze when loading the editor.

I've uninstall Anaconda an reinstall it whithout succes

I've launched Spyder from commmand line and I've no specific output in the terminal

I've deleted the .spyder-py3  .anaconda .ipython and .conda whithout change

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: Can you launch it from the command prompt with show console? "spyder --show-console"

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting it just says: 

spyder --show-console
(Deprecated) --show console does nothing, now the default  behavior is to show the console, use --hide-console if you want to hide it

And nothing more and it doesn't return

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is most probably a antivirus/firewall issue. So please deactivate or even uninstall them and try again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thanks for your reply; I've uninstall my a antivirus/firewall, uninstall anaconda, reboot and reinstall anaconda but it still won't load

Comment: Just to be clear, here is a screenshot when it freeze https://imgur.com/a/WORiIIK

Comment: No idea then, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've reinstalled windows and Anaconda and now everything work like a charm